# Get drawRect to redraw shape every x seconds

Tags: swift

I come from javascript where drawing on the canvas or with divs is as easy as setting up the attributes of the object to be drawn and then calling a setInterval or requestAnimationFrame to update position and redraw.

I want to be able to do this with swift in xcode basically but I can't find any tutorials that have helped me enough to do it alone.

I have been able to draw whatever I want using drawRect but I have no idea how to set it up so it will redraw the shape I made as the coordinates change, for example, every 30ms. I just want to do it in the simplest way possible.

Let's say I have a class, drawExample, with this code inside it:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, shapePosX, shapePosY + 0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, shapePosX + 250, shapePosY + 320)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, shapePosX + 300, shapePosY + 320)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, shapePosX + 0, shapePosY + 0)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillPath(context)
}
```

And I just want to update the shapePosX and shapePosY using a timer

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a better way than drawRect(). That's way too brute force.

Comment: are there other ways to draw shapes/lines/etc? I'm really just going for simple just to get a start, I am not worried about performance or quality too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to leverage UIView & UIViewControllers's built in redraw as well as a timer. You'll do this from within the UIViewController:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0,
                             repeats: true,
                             block: { (timer) in 
                                self.view.setNeedsDisplay() 
                             })
```

Note** it is setNeedsDisplay() that triggers the UIView to redraw.